# What is the maximum number of character changes for different Unicode normalization form?

Tags: unicode

Using different Unicode normalization forms may result in different length of output for the same input. For example:

```py
>>> import unicodedata
>>> c = "å"
>>> a = len(unicodedata.normalize("NFC", c))
>>> b = len(unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", c))
>>> print(a, b)
1 2
```

When you change `c`, what is the maximum value of `b/a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the time of writing (Unicode 13.0), the biggest length difference between a character’s NFC and NFKD expansions is a factor of **18**. U+FDFA ﷺ ARABIC LIGATURE SALLALLAHOU ALAYHE WASALLAM is unaffected by normalisation forms C and D, but decomposes into a sequence of 18 codepoints (صلى الله عليه وسلم) under KC and KD.

However, there is no formally defined limit to this in the standard. Future updates could in theory add a new character with an even longer decomposition mapping. The Unicode Standard only guarantees an upper bound for NFC. Per [Unicode Stability Policy](https://www.unicode.org/policies/stability_policy.html#Property_Value):

> Canonical mappings (`Decomposition_Mapping` property values) are always
>   limited so that no string when normalized to NFC expands to more than
>   3× in length (measured in code units).